# PHP Switch Conditional Statement Better Way

Tags: php, optimization, switch-statement, conditional-operator

What is the best way to optimize this code? I know that if and else statements will be faster, but I want something that will be clean and concise.  Any ideas?

```
switch ($data['months']) {
case ($data['months'] >= 400):
    $data['months'] = 400;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 360):
    $data['months'] = 360;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 60):
    $data['months'] = 60;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 48):
    $data['months'] = 48;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 36):
    $data['months'] = 36;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 24):
    $data['months'] = 24;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 12):
    $data['months'] = 12;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 9):
    $data['months'] = 9;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 6):
    $data['months'] = 6;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 3):
    $data['months'] = 3;
    break;
case ($data['months'] >= 1):
    $data['months'] = 1;
    break;
default:
    $data['months'] = 12;
}
```

Comment: Off topic here, try asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) with an array of breakpoints.

```
$breakpoints = array(400, 360, 60, 48, 36, 24, 12, 9, 6, 3, 1);

// Loop through each breakpoints
foreach($breakpoints as $breakpoint){

    // Proceed to next breakpoint
    if($data['months'] < $breakpoint)
        continue;

    // No need to loop through the rest of the array
    $data['months'] = $breakpoint;
    break;

}

// Handle the cases where $data['month'] is less than 1
if($data['months'] < 1)
    $data['months'] = 12;
```

#### Update

An alternative would be checking if the `$data['months']` is less than 1 before the loop:

```
if($data['months'] < 1)
    $data['months'] = 12;
else{

    $breakpoints = array(400, 360, 60, 48, 36, 24, 12, 9, 6, 3, 1);

    // Loop through each breakpoints
    foreach($breakpoints as $breakpoint){

        // Proceed to next breakpoint
        if($data['months'] < $breakpoint)
            continue;

        // No need to loop through the rest of the array
        $data['months'] = $breakpoint;
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Though you were first to respond, I chose the next answer since the setting of the default value was much cleaner and eliminated an additional conditional check.

Comment: @Bryce True, but it's looping through each breakpoints and reassigning the `$data['months']` even though it doesn't need to...

Comment: Good point, I think I'll take mix of them both. haha. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryce I just noticed that the way @ceejayoz did it, no matter your initial value of `$data['months']`... after the loop, it's going to be `12`. Since it's overwriting the initial value before the `foreach`.

Comment: Yup, just realized this as well, hence why I have marked yours as the correct answer :).

Comment: @Bryce I updated my answer to handle the default case better. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You too!  Thanks again!

Comment: No need for `continue` and the check for 1 can be an `else` inside the loop `if`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
$breakpoints = [1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 360, 400];

foreach($breakpoints as $breakpoint) {
    if($data['months'] >= $breakpoint) {
        $value = $breakpoint;
    }
}

if(!isset($value)) { $value = 12; }
```

Comment: I'd note, though, that your `default` in the switch doesn't make sense to me. `$data['months']` is never gonna be `1` in your code - I kept that weirdness.

Comment: I don't think this will work because you're assigning the `$data['months']` to `12` by default. So after your loop, no matter the initial value, the `$data['months']` will be equal to `12`.

Comment: @ChinLeung Yeah, you're right. Brain's not working great today.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with in the end.

```
$breakpoints = [400, 360, 240, 120, 60, 48, 36, 24, 12, 9, 6, 3, 1, null];
foreach($breakpoints as $breakpoint){
    if($data['months'] >= $breakpoint) {
        $data['months'] = $breakpoint ? $breakpoint : 12;
        break;
    }
}
```